# Qt open-source library to draw routers with links?

Tags: qt, open-source, widget, drawing, diagram

I want to draw a network topology diagram with qt.
To simplify, I only need to draw routers, pcs and links between them, but I want the routers able to **be dragged with links with mouse** and to save all the widgets into a file and reopened if possible.
The diagram will be only part of my program, I plan to configure the routers and computers and complete other functions, too.
Any good links or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find using graphics libraries with a scene graph much easier to provide solutions for tasks you describe. Unfortunately QT and GTK lacks the flexibility that the Browser (SVG, Canvas) or Flash platform offer but there were some scene graph integration into QT and GTK with [Clutter library](http://blogs.gnome.org/clutter/) can well be a viable option.

Here is something to investigate for QT:
http://zchydem.enume.net/2010/11/01/playing-with-qt-scene-graph/